# How to join two tables in SQL Server, where the IDs are not the same?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables in MS SQL and I am using MS Studio. The first table is called register it has a list of fields. The second table is called Plan and it has a list of fields.

- The unique key in the table register is called `RegisterID`
- The unique key in the table Plan is called `RegisterID`

The goal is to link with a `left join` the Register to the Plan. My difficulty is that the `IDs` are not exactly the same: An ID in Plan is `xxxx` (`xxxx` being the value of the ID). An ID in Register is `xxxx_0` (`xxxx` being the same value than Plan was added _0)

What is the solution to link those 2 tables in a simple query with fields of both tables?

Here is some more information.

You will find the 2 tables and the expect result of the query.
Tables structure
[image]

Expected result

[image]

Please note that I am a beginner.

Comment: Just remove '_0' with a REPLACE ... Register.RegisterID = REPLACE(Plan.RegisterID, '_0', '')

Comment: can you please show your tables structure with data ? and your expected result?

Comment: From next time request you to ask question with formatted text DDL, Sample data as input, what you have trying and current result and expected result in text format so someone can consume it in their query. Images are not helpful most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the characters to the first field or remove them from the second

```
select * 
from register 
left outer join plan on register.RegisterID+'_0' = plan.RegisterID
```

```
select * 
from register 
left outer join plan on register.RegisterID = REPLACE(plan.RegisterID,'_0','')
```

If the length of the ID is always the same there is a third option

```
select * 
from register 
left outer join plan on register.RegisterID = LEFT(plan.RegisterID,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
 SELECT *
  FROM Register R
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [Plan] P
  ON LEFT(R.RegisterID, LEN(R.RegisterID) - 2) = P.RegisterID
```

The expression `LEFT(R.RegisterID, LEN(R.RegisterID) - 2)` will remove the '_0' from Register.RegisterID and the JOIN will work.